# Setting nextKeyView in IB; key view order is different when the app is run

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, first-responder

I have a window full of text fields and buttons and I want to set its key view order in a particular way.
So, I set the `initialFirstResponder` to the first text field and correctly set the `nextKeyView` one by one for each control.

This has NO effect when running the app. When I use the Tab key to change the key field or button, it jumps differently than the order I set -- it seems `nextKeyView` is not working.

I tested it in another sample app, and it works great, but in this app it is not working.

If it helps, I have tab view with three tabs in my window.

Comment: I found the reason, I have to set the current tab's initialFirstResponder to the first textfield instead of window's firstResponder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dudes, I found my answer.

the problem will solve if we set **initialFirstResponder** of **current selected Tab** to the first field or button of the Tab and the root of problem is that when we use the **Tab View** in our window then the first responder changes to the tab controller.

I putted the answer for other guys who may face this simple problem.

Thanks all anyway.